# Swipe left/right not working in Android emulator - React Native app

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

Is there a setting to allow swipe gestures in the emulator? I am using react-navigation, but also am using react-native-swipe-gestures and no swipe, left or right, is working on any page under any circumstance. I go to Chrome in the emulator and go from page to page and still cannot swipe left or right within Chrome (am I supposed to be able to swipe in Chrome in Android?)

I am unfamiliar with Android - is there something I am missing? I have a very big, complicated app and am just now testing in Android. Everything works great in iOS.

I have implemented [this](https://aboutreact.com/swipe-gestures-not-working-in-android/) already to install react-navigation properly for Android and linked everything properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in react-navigation, I did not have gesturesEnabled=true. According to [the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#gesturesenabled), this property defaults to true in iOS (which is why I had no problems in iOS) and false in Android. So you could add `gesturesEnabled: true` in each of your screen's navigation options, or set defaultNavigationOptions with that property in each stack if you have multiple stacks or tons of screens.

So as the last item in your stack add...

```
{
  defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      gesturesEnabled: true,
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is due to the mouse not fully representing a finger in the emulate. Use an Android device or VMOS to fix this.